# Ordenar vetor do menor para o maior

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, for

```
  PHP:
    array_push($var, $linha['data']);
    array_push($var, $linha['data_t']);
    array_push($var, $linha['data_f']);

    usort($var);// Adicionei essa linha para tentar formatar as datas da menor pra maior mas retornou o erro
```

Warning: usort() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

```
    $var = array_unique($var); 

    foreach ($var as $v) {
    echo  "<td><div class='data'>" . $v . "</div></td>";
    }





  JS:
  var data = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < $(".data").length ; i++)
  { 
     data[i] =  $(".data").eq(i).text();
  }
```

Tenho esse laço que pega a data do php.
O problema é que na hora dele imprimir ele imprime por exemplo:02/05,05/05,01/05.
Gostaria de ordenar a variável `data[]` por ordem crescente de data.
Pego a data em uma Sql no formato date(%dd/%mm) ou seja 00/00

Comment: a data é só isso? vou esperar vc fazer a pergunta corretamente. A anterior que vc fez me gerou duvidas na resposta. Isso não é uma data valida, é uma string

Comment: A variavel recebe uma data, só gostaria de ordenar de forma crescente

Comment: yy é ano tá correto?

Comment: data é algo assim `2018-08-12`

Comment: Perdão é dia e mês

Comment: Já está no formato correto exemplo 30/05 com a "/" tbm

Comment: Certo, obgd pela atenção

Comment: Usei a função usort no php, ela ordenou porém uma data 00/00 ficou na frente das outras kk

Comment: e de onde saiu essa data 00/00 ?

Comment: Deve ser algum dado q esteja sem data, tenho que verificar mais afundo. Houve uma coincidencia da busca que fiz vir com as datas em sequencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//função para ordenar
function comparaPorTimeStamp($time1, $time2)
{
    if (strtotime($time1) > strtotime($time2))
        return 1;
    else if (strtotime($time1) < strtotime($time2)) 
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}


$var = array("12/08", "13/08", "06/08");

array_push($var, "10/08");
array_push($var, "15/08");
array_push($var,"11/08");       

$var = array_unique($var);  

$lista = array();

foreach( $var as $value ) {
    //inverte dia com mes e substitui por traço
    $value= join("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$value)));

    /*******já que só tem dia e mês podemos acrescentar qualquer ano para
    formar uma data digna de ser comparada *****************************/

    $arquivo= "2018-".$value;
    //cria o array
    $lista[] .= $arquivo;
}       

//ordena por data crescente
usort($lista, "comparaPorTimeStamp");

/*******************************
vamos ao que interessa ↓
*******************************/

$datas = array();

foreach( $lista as $valor ) {
    $valor=str_replace("2018-","",$valor);
    $valor= join("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$valor)));
    $datas[] .= $valor;
}

print_r($datas);
```

[**exemplo rodando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/EQNDWY)

[**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) — aceita uma string, no formato “data/hora em em inglês”, e realiza um parse nela transformando em um timestamp.

**O que é Timestamp (unix time)?**

Timestamp (ou Unix Time) é o número inteiro que representa a quantidade de segundos que se passaram desde o dia 1 de janeiro de 1970 com base no meridiano de Greenwich (GMT), que é o fuso horário 0 (zero).

[**usort**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) - Ordena um array pelos valores utilizando uma função de comparação definida pelo usuário